# UISearchController's UISearchBar suddenly changes position of self and Parent VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem with `UISearchBar`. When I use just a `UISearchBar` it works totally fine. But I want to have `Cancel` button and some other `UISearchController`'s features available.
Unfortunately my `SearchViewController` has to be presented in a popup (i'm using the `Presentr` CocoaPod).
Problem occurs only when i click on the `UISearchBar`.

Without focus on `UISearchBar`:
[image]

With focus and toggled keyboard (the same fragment of the screen):
[image]

It simply moves far to the left. It is cut off because of Presentr's popup frame.

And here's the code:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    private let doneButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    private var data: [String]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        setupViews()
    }
    init(data: [String]) {
        self.data = data
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
        searchController.searchBar.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.top.equalToSuperview()
        }
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(searchController.searchBar.snp.bottom)
            make.bottom.right.left.equalToSuperview()
        }
        extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search your country code"
        tableView.tableFooterView = doneButton
        definesPresentationContext = true
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    }
}
```

Please forget about `doneButton`, it's just unused yet.